# Jest - Is there a way to assert the complete JSON response data structure with few exceptions to handle dynamic values inside the JSON?

Tags: typescript, jestjs, integration-testing

I am trying to validate a JSON response from an API and currently using ".toEqual" function to do it. I like to use toEqual operator since it provides an exact match. This worked fine till i had to test a response with dynamic values and hence wondering if there are any readymade options to generalize the dyonamic validation or i should implement an extension to ".toEqual" locally (or any other better ways to make this possible with least effort also)

Now to speak with examples:

#Thought process on how i want to define and validate a response

```
definition:{
    status: 200,
    exec: pass,
    a: "apple",
    data: {
            b: string
            },
    id: integer,
    createdOn: DateTime
};

actual: {
    status: 200,
    exec: pass,
    a: "apple",
    data: {b: "ball"},
    id: 50,
    createdOn: "25-10-2019 17:49 EST"
}
//The above actual response should validate to true for the definition
```

How can i achieve this in Jest ?
I am using nodejs + typescript. So if not in jest, how else ?

Answer (score 0):

Achieved this with the use of snapshots feature available in jest,

```
test(`Sample to show the feature of snapshots`, () => {
    const definition = {
        status: 200,
        exec: pass,
        a: "apple",
        data: {
                b: expect.any(String)
            },
        id: expect.any(Number),
        createdOn: expect.any(Date)
    };

    const actual = {
        status: 200,
        exec: pass,
        a: "apple",
        data: {
                b: "ball"
            },
        id: 50,
        createdOn: "25-10-2019 17:49 EST"
    }
    return expect(actual).toMatchSnapshot(definition);
});

//The Date part alone will have to be formatted and tested yet, but guess you get the idea..
```